# How to get MORH-II database

Tags: matlab, textures, face-recognition

I need to get MORH-II database for my research which is about age invariant using face recognition

Is there anyone who knows how I can find it ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A quick search for MORH-II database finds nothing I can see, but does result in quite a few hits for [MORPH-II as a dataset](https://ebill.uncw.edu/C20231_ustores/web/product_detail.jsp?PRODUCTID=8). It appears that you need to pay for it: $99 for academic use. I suggest you'd better get $99 together....

Comment: thanks for your help but it is difficult to pay this amount of money . In some papers I found that this database is free for academic purposes.

Comment: OK. Your question, then, is a bit ambiguous. What you are asking is can anyone tell you how to get it for free. You could always email an author of one of the papers that says it is free, or spend time with a search engine...